# Can you pick an advanced rogue talent with the Extra Rogue Talent feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, rogue, pathfinder-society

If you are level 11 (or above) and you take the Extra Rogue Talent feat (as rogue), can you pick an advanced talent instead of just a normal rogue talent?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 7):

### It is unclear

The [Rogue Talent](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Rogue/#TOC-Rogue-Talents) class ability says:

> As a rogue gains experience, she learns a number of talents that aid her and confound her foes. Starting at 2nd level, a rogue gains one rogue talent. She gains **an additional rogue talent for every 2 levels** of rogue attained after 2nd level.

The feat [Extra Rogue Talent](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-rogue-talent/) says:

> Benefit: You gain one additional rogue talent. You must meet all of the prerequisites for this rogue talent.

Finally, the [Advanced Talents](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Rogue/#TOC-Advanced-Talents) class ability says:

> **At 10th level**, and every two levels thereafter, a rogue can choose one of the following advanced talents **in place of a rogue talent**.

I bolded the relevant parts, which state that the rogue talents gained every 2 levels can be advanced talents, and you replace a talent normally gained at those levels by an advanced talent instead. This is controversial, however, and I have never seen any developer comment stating whether the *Extra Talent* should allow you to get advanced talents or not.

The only reference of rogue talents and advanced talents being different is on the (optional) [retraining](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining/) rules:

> Rogue: Retrain one rogue talent or advanced rogue talent.

For the feat to work for advanced talents, it would have to mention something about it, similar to the wording about how [Paladins](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin#TOC-Mercy-Su-) add new *Mercies* to their list of options as they level up instead of modifying the *Mercy* class ability to allow you to pick more options every *n* levels.

However, I know that *many* GMs allow you to pick a new *Advanced Talent* when taking that feat after 11th level, just like allowing *Major* and *Grand* *hexes* for witches, or *Master* *tricks* for ninja, etc. The game doesn't really break apart because of that, and those classes (except the witch) should get some help to be competitive at later levels.

The [Extra Amplification](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-amplification/) talent, for instance, says that this extra *phrenic amplification* cannot be a *Major Amplification*. The psychic class mechanic is similar to the Rogue's talents ability, except they are gained every 3 levels.

> You gain one additional phrenic amplification. **This can’t be a major amplification**.

With this in mind, I personally would allow you to take *Extra Talent* to add an extra advanced talent to your character.

Comment: I know it's *technically* unclear, but—seriously—does the game *ever* allow *every variation of X* to be picked when it says *X* can be picked and when *X* exists independently? I mean, a wizard can pick a familiar, but that doesn't entitle a wizard to an improved or tumor familiar, and a fighter can deal with his sword damage, but that doesn't entitle the fighter to deal with his sword sonic or Charisma ability damage. I appreciate you accommodating those "many GMs," but that doesn't make 'em right!

Comment: If you disagree with the premise of the answer, make a competing answer.

Comment: I looked up for PFS specific rulings and found nothing concrete. I know this hardly comes up in PFS due yo the level range, but I honestly expected this to have been addressed at least once by a venture captain or coordinator. My issue with this is due to how they worded it for psychics.